# Recursive Breadth First Search Knights Tour

Tags: c#, performance, recursion, breadth-first-search, chess

This program was written on Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2012 Professional. Some of the issues encountered may have been fixed or changed in a more recent version.

This is a quote from my [second question](/questions/123489/recursive-breadth-first-search-for-knights-tour) in response to a comment made below:

*The algorithm in KnightMovesImplementation.cs implements a recursive tree search for all possible paths of a Knight on a Chess Board from point A to point B with the given restrictions of board size and slicing . The tree is implemented as a recursive algorithm rather than a data structure. The data structures used in the algorithm are paths (a collection of moves from the origin to the destination), moves (the 8 possi ble moves a Knight can make on a Chess Board), and locations (squares on the chessboard represented by row number and column number).*

*Slicing can be either the Knight can't visit a previously visited row or column on the board, or the Knight can't visit a previously visited square on the board.*

My second question here on Code Review is [here](/questions/123489/recursive-breadth-first-search-for-knights-tour). It was as a request for review of my C++ and as an answer to [this question](/questions/123085/calculating-all-possible-knight-turns-chess/123669#123669). The author of that question asked me if I could provide a solution in C# since he was first learning C# and didn't know C++. I hope he didn't hold his breath waiting because that was 3 months ago, but here is my C# version. To write this solution I had to take a detour and refactor my original post which I asked [last week](/questions/132876/knights-tour-improved-refactored-recursive-breadth-first-search-for).

Only three main files are shown here. You can find the entire program on [GitHub](https://github.com/pacmaninbw/CSharpKnightMoves/tree/98d2a3842cb797b79afa29e0aee78563cc84856a). The three files are the core algorithm (`KnightMoveImplementation` and `KMMoveFilters`) and the Program.cs file.

Since it is my first C# program, I'd really love someone to dissect it and tell me all the things I can do to improve it.

**Sample Output**

> ```
> Do you want to print each of the resulting paths? (y/n)  
> Select the number of the test case you want to run.  
> Test Case #   Start Name  Target Name Board Size  Slicing Method  
> 1 A3  H4  8   Can't return to previous row or column  
> 2 A1  H8  8   Can't return to previous row or column  
> 3 A8  H1  8   Can't return to previous row or column  
> 4 B3  H4  8   Can't return to previous row or column  
> 5 B3  H8  8   Can't return to previous row or column  
> 6 C1  H4  8   Can't return to previous row or column  
> 7 A3  H8  8   Can't return to previous row or column  
> 8 A3  H4  8   Can't return to previous row or column  
> 9 H4  A3  8   Can't return to previous row or column  
> 10    D4  A8  8   Can't return to previous row or column  
> 11    D4  E6  8   Can't return to previous row or column  
> 12    A3  B5  8   Can't return to previous row or column  
> 13    A3  B5  13  Can't return to previous row or column  
> 14    A3  B5  8   Can't return to previous location  
> 15    A3  B5  26  Can't return to previous row or column  
> 16    All of the above except for 15 and 14
> 17    All of the above (Go get lunch)
>
> finished computation at 7/1/2016 12:57:41 PM  
> elapsed time: 0.0144886 Seconds  
>
>
> The point of origin for all path searches was  A3  
> The destination point for all path searches was  H4  
> The number of squares on each edge of the board is 8  
> The slicing methodology used to further limit searches was no repeat visits to any rows or columns.  
> There are 5 Resulting Paths  
> There were 276 attempted paths  
> The average path length is 4.8  
> The median path length is 4  
> The longest path is 6 moves.  
> The shortest path is 4 moves.  
> ######################### End of Test Case A3 to  H4#########################  
>
> finished computation at 7/1/2016 12:57:41 PM  
> elapsed time: 0.0006995 Seconds  
>
>
> The point of origin for all path searches was  A1  
> The destination point for all path searches was  H8  
> The number of squares on each edge of the board is 8  
> The slicing methodology used to further limit searches was no repeat visits to any rows or columns.  
> There are 18 Resulting Paths  
> There were 138 attempted paths  
> The average path length is 6  
> The median path length is 6  
> The longest path is 6 moves.  
> The shortest path is 6 moves.  
> ######################### End of Test Case A1 to  H8#########################  
>
> finished computation at 7/1/2016 12:57:41 PM  
> elapsed time: 0.0018398 Seconds  
>
>
> The point of origin for all path searches was  B3  
> The destination point for all path searches was  H4  
> The number of squares on each edge of the board is 8  
> The slicing methodology used to further limit searches was no repeat visits to any rows or columns.  
> There are 7 Resulting Paths  
> There were 330 attempted paths  
> The average path length is 4.71428571428571  
> The median path length is 5  
> The longest path is 5 moves.  
> The shortest path is 3 moves.  
> ######################### End of Test Case B3 to  H4#########################
> ```

**KnightMovesImplementation.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace KnightMoves_CSharp
{
    class KnightMovesImplementation {
        /*
         * This class provides the search for all the paths a Knight on a chess
         * board can take from the point of origin to the destination. It
         * implements a modified Knights Tour. The classic knights tour problem
         * is to visit every location on the chess board without returning to a
         * previous location. That is a single path for the knight. This
         * implementation returns all possible paths from point a to point b.
         *      
         * The current implementation is a Recursive Breadth First Search. Conceptually
         * the algorithm implements a B+ tree with a maximum of 8 possible branches
         * at each level. The root of the tree is the point of origin. A particular
         * path terminates in a leaf. A leaf is the result of either reaching the
         * destination, or reaching a point where there are no more branches to
         * traverse.
         * 
         * The public interface CalculatePaths establishes the root and creates
         * the first level of branching. The protected interface CalculatePath
         * performs the recursive depth first search, however, the
         * MoveFilters.GetPossibleMoves() function it calls performs a breadth
         * first search of the current level.
         */
        KMBoardLocation PointOfOrigin;
        KMBoardLocation Destination;
        uint SingleSideBoardDimension;
        KnightMovesMethodLimitations PathLimitations;
        KMOutputData Results;
        KMMoveFilters MoveFilter;
        KMPath m_Path;

        public KnightMovesImplementation(KMBaseData UserInputData)
        {
            SingleSideBoardDimension = UserInputData.DimensionOneSide;
            PathLimitations = UserInputData.LimitationsOnMoves;
            InitPointOfOrigin(UserInputData);
            InitDestination(UserInputData);
            Results = new KMOutputData(PointOfOrigin, Destination, SingleSideBoardDimension, PathLimitations);
            MoveFilter = new KMMoveFilters(PointOfOrigin, SingleSideBoardDimension, PathLimitations);
            m_Path = new KMPath();
        }

        public KMOutputData CalculatePaths()
        {
            List<KMMove> PossibleFirstMoves = MoveFilter.GetPossibleMoves(PointOfOrigin);

            if (PossibleFirstMoves.Count == 0)
            {
                // Anywhere on the board should have at between 2 and 8 possible moves
                throw new ApplicationException("KnightMovesImplementation::CalculatePaths: No Possible Moves.");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (KMMove CurrentMove in PossibleFirstMoves)
                {
                    CurrentMove.SetOriginCalculateDestination(PointOfOrigin);
                    if (CurrentMove.IsValid() == true) {
                        CalculatePath(CurrentMove);
                    }
                }
            }
            return Results;
        }

        protected void InitPointOfOrigin(KMBaseData UserInputData)
        {
            PointOfOrigin = new KMBoardLocation(UserInputData.StartRow, UserInputData.StartColumn, SingleSideBoardDimension);
            PointOfOrigin.SetName(UserInputData.StartName);
        }

        protected void InitDestination(KMBaseData UserInputData)
        {
            Destination = new KMBoardLocation(UserInputData.TargetRow, UserInputData.TargetColumn, SingleSideBoardDimension);
            Destination.SetName(UserInputData.TargetName);
        }
        /*
         * Recursive algorith that performs a depth search.
         * The call to CurrentMove.GetNextLocation() implements the breadth-first portion
         * of the search.
         */
        protected void CalculatePath(KMMove CurrentMove)
        {
            KMBoardLocation CurrentLocation = CurrentMove.GetNextLocation();
            m_Path.AddMoveToPath(CurrentMove);
            MoveFilter.PushVisited(CurrentLocation);

                if (Destination.IsSameLocation(CurrentLocation) == true)
                {
                    Results.IncrementAttemptedPaths();
                    Results.AddPath(m_Path);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (CurrentMove.IsValid() == true)
                    {
                        List<KMMove> PossibleMoves = MoveFilter.GetPossibleMoves(CurrentLocation);
                        if (PossibleMoves.Count != 0)
                        {
                            foreach (KMMove NextMove in PossibleMoves)
                            {
                                CalculatePath(NextMove);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Results.IncrementAttemptedPaths();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("In KnightMovesImplementation::CalculatePath CurrentLocation Not Valid");
                    }
                }
                // Backup to previous location
            MoveFilter.PopVisited();
            m_Path.RemoveLastMove();
        }
    };
}
```

**KMMoveFilters.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace KnightMoves_CSharp
{
        /*
         * This class provides all the possible Knight moves for a specified location
         * on the chess board. In the center of the chess board there are 8 possible
         * moves. In the middle of the edge on the chess board there are 4 possible
         * moves. In a corner of the chess board there are 2 possible moves. The
         * location on the board provides the first filter.
         * Slicing is used to allow the program to complete in a reasonable finite
         * amount of time. The slicing method can be varied, the default slicing
         * method is the knight can't return to any row or column it has previously
         * visited. The slicing is the second filter.
         */
    public class KMMoveFilters {
        private struct LocationBase { public uint Row; public uint Column; }
        // The 8 possible moves the knight can make.
        public static int MAIXMUM_POSSIBLE_MOVES = 8;
        private KMMove Left1Up2;
        private KMMove Left2Up1;
        private KMMove Left2Down1;
        private KMMove Left1Down2;
        private KMMove Right1Up2;
        private KMMove Right2Up1;
        private KMMove Right2Down1;
        private KMMove Right1Down2;

        const int Left1 = -1;
        const int Left2 = -2;
        const int Down1 = -1;
        const int Down2 = -2;
        const int Right1 = 1;
        const int Right2 = 2;
        const int Up1 = 1;
        const int Up2 = 2;

        List<KMMove> AllPossibleMoves = new List<KMMove>();

        private uint BoardDimension;
        public uint GetBoardDimension() { return BoardDimension; }

        KnightMovesMethodLimitations PathLimitations;
        Stack<LocationBase> VisitedLocations = new Stack<LocationBase>();
        Stack<uint> VisitedRows = new Stack<uint>();
        Stack<uint> VisitedColumns = new Stack<uint>();

        public KMMoveFilters(KMBoardLocation Origin, uint SingleSideBoardDimension, KnightMovesMethodLimitations VisitationLimitations)
        {
            PathLimitations = VisitationLimitations;
            BoardDimension = SingleSideBoardDimension;

            Left1Up2 = new KMMove(Left1, Up2, BoardDimension);
            Left2Up1 = new KMMove(Left2, Up1, BoardDimension);
            Left2Down1 = new KMMove(Left2, Down1, BoardDimension);
            Left1Down2 = new KMMove(Left1, Down2, BoardDimension);
            Right1Up2 = new KMMove(Right1, Up2, BoardDimension);
            Right2Up1 = new KMMove(Right2, Up1, BoardDimension);
            Right2Down1 = new KMMove(Right2, Down1, BoardDimension);
            Right1Down2 = new KMMove(Right1, Down2, BoardDimension);

            AllPossibleMoves.Add(Left1Up2);
            AllPossibleMoves.Add(Left2Up1);
            AllPossibleMoves.Add(Left2Down1);
            AllPossibleMoves.Add(Left1Down2);
            AllPossibleMoves.Add(Right1Up2);
            AllPossibleMoves.Add(Right2Up1);
            AllPossibleMoves.Add(Right2Down1);
            AllPossibleMoves.Add(Right1Down2);

            // Record the initial location so we never return
            LocationBase PtOfOrigin = new LocationBase();
            PtOfOrigin.Row = Origin.GetRow();
            PtOfOrigin.Column = Origin.GetColumn();
            VisitedLocations.Push(PtOfOrigin);
        }
        /*
         * C# does not seem to provide a default copy constructor so copy AllPossibleMoves
         */
        private List<KMMove> GetAllPossibleMoves() { return CopyAllPossibleMoves(); }

        private List<KMMove> CopyAllPossibleMoves()
        {
            List<KMMove> PublicCopy = new List<KMMove>();
            foreach (KMMove PossibleMove in AllPossibleMoves)
            {
                PublicCopy.Add(new KMMove(PossibleMove));
            }

            return PublicCopy;
        }

        public List<KMMove> GetPossibleMoves(KMBoardLocation Origin)
        {
            if (Origin.IsValid() == false)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("KMMoveFilters::GetPossibleMoves : Parameter Origin is not valid!\n");
            }

            List<KMMove> TempAllPossibleMoves = GetAllPossibleMoves();
            List<KMMove> PossibleMoves = new List<KMMove>();
            foreach (KMMove PossibeMove in TempAllPossibleMoves)
            {
                PossibeMove.SetOriginCalculateDestination(Origin);
                if ((PossibeMove.IsValid() == true) && (IsNotPreviouslyVisited(PossibeMove.GetNextLocation()) == true))
                {
                    PossibleMoves.Add(PossibeMove);
                }
            }
            return PossibleMoves;
        }

        protected bool IsNotPreviouslyVisited(KMBoardLocation PossibleDestination)
        {
            bool NotPrevioslyVisited = true;
            LocationBase PossibleLocation;

            PossibleLocation.Row = PossibleDestination.GetRow();
            PossibleLocation.Column = PossibleDestination.GetColumn(); 
            // We can't ever go back to a previously visited location
            if (VisitedLocations.Count != 0)
            {
                if (VisitedLocations.Contains(PossibleLocation) == true)
                {
                    NotPrevioslyVisited = false;
                }
            }
            switch (PathLimitations)
            {
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("KMPath::CheckMoveAgainstPreviousLocations : Unknown type of Path Limitation.");
                case KnightMovesMethodLimitations.DenyByPreviousLocation:
                    // Handled above by VisitedLocations.Contains().
                    break;
                case KnightMovesMethodLimitations.DenyByPreviousRowOrColumn:
                    if ((VisitedRows.Count != 0) && (VisitedColumns.Count != 0))
                    {
                        if (VisitedRows.Contains(PossibleDestination.GetRow()) == true)
                        {
                            NotPrevioslyVisited = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (VisitedColumns.Contains(PossibleDestination.GetColumn()) == true)
                        {
                            NotPrevioslyVisited = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return NotPrevioslyVisited;
        }

        public void PushVisited(KMBoardLocation Location)
        {
            LocationBase TestLocation = new LocationBase();

            TestLocation.Row = Location.GetRow();
            TestLocation.Row = Location.GetRow();

            VisitedLocations.Push(TestLocation);
            VisitedRows.Push(Location.GetRow());
            VisitedColumns.Push(Location.GetColumn());
        }

        public void PopVisited()
        {
            VisitedRows.Pop();
            VisitedColumns.Pop();
            VisitedLocations.Pop();
        }

    };

}
```

**Program.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace KnightMoves_CSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void OutputOverAllStatistics(List<double> TestTimes)
        {
            if (TestTimes.Count < 1)    // Prevent Division by 0 in Average
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No test times to run statistics on!");
                return;
            }

            TestTimes.Sort();   // Sort once for Min, Median and Max
            Console.WriteLine("\nOverall Results");
            Console.WriteLine("The average execution time is {0} seconds.", TestTimes.Average()); 
            Console.WriteLine("The median execution time is {0} seconds.", TestTimes[TestTimes.Count() / 2]);
            Console.WriteLine("The longest execution time is {0} seconds.", TestTimes[TestTimes.Count - 1]);
            Console.WriteLine("The shortest execution time is {0} seconds.", TestTimes[0]);
        }

        static double ExecutionLoop(KMBaseData UserInputData, bool ShowPathData)
        {
            Stopwatch StopWatch = new Stopwatch();

            KnightMovesImplementation KnightPathFinder = new KnightMovesImplementation(UserInputData);
            StopWatch.Start();
            KMOutputData OutputData = KnightPathFinder.CalculatePaths();
            StopWatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan ts = StopWatch.Elapsed;
            Double ElapsedTimeForOutPut = ts.TotalSeconds;

            Console.Write("finished computation at ");
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            Console.WriteLine("elapsed time: {0} Seconds", ElapsedTimeForOutPut);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            OutputData.ShowPathData(ShowPathData);
            OutputData.ShowResults();

            return ElapsedTimeForOutPut;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool ShowPathData = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to print each of the resulting paths? (y/n)");
            string ShowPathAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
            ShowPathData = (ShowPathAnswer.ToLower() == "y");

            KMTestData TestData = new KMTestData();
            List<KMBaseData> ListOfTestCases = TestData.LetUserEnterTestCaseNumber();

            try
            {
                List<double> TestTimes = new List<double>();

                foreach (KMBaseData TestCase in ListOfTestCases)
                {
                    TestTimes.Add(ExecutionLoop(TestCase, ShowPathData));
                    GC.Collect();
                }

                OutputOverAllStatistics(TestTimes);
                return;
            }

            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
            {
                Console.Error.Write("A fatal range error occurred in KnightMoves: ");
                Console.Error.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                return;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException e)
            {
                Console.Error.Write("A fatal argument error occurred in KnightMoves: ");
                Console.Error.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                return;
            }
            catch (ApplicationException e)
            {
                Console.Error.Write("A fatal application error occurred in KnightMoves: ");
                Console.Error.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what the program is supposed to do? I mean what input does it expect and what does it do with it? I understand it calculates knight moves but from where to where etc? The general idea behind it.

Comment: @t3chb0t I've copied what the program does from my original question. It is now in the body of the question.

Comment: Is this really breadth-first? Breadth-first searches are rarely done recursively.

Comment: @200_success The function KMMoveFilters::GetPossibleMoves() does a one step search to the next level. I was debating the issue myself and looked both breadth first and depth first on Wikipedia, by the articles I found it is breadth first.

Comment: @t3chb0t I have added what I hope are meaningful comments to the code, they existed in the refactored C++ version but were missing in this version. The GitHub version has also been updated.

Comment: Please note, the GitHub version has modifications to the code, in addition to the comments I mention above, many variables in the classes were made private. I did not want to change the code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some unorganized comments:

`NotPrevioslyVisited` has a typo, should be `NotPreviouslyVisited`.

---

```
if (VisitedLocations.Count != 0)
{
    if (VisitedLocations.Contains(PossibleLocation) == true)
    {
        NotPrevioslyVisited = false;
    }
}
```

You can combine if statements here - and there's no need to explicitly check for `true`. `if (VisitedLocations.Count != 0 && VisitedLocations.Contains(PossibleLocation))` will do.

---

```
if (PossibleFirstMoves.Count == 0)
{
    // Anywhere on the board should have at between 2 and 8 possible moves
    throw new ApplicationException("KnightMovesImplementation::CalculatePaths: No Possible Moves.");
}
else
{
    foreach (KMMove CurrentMove in PossibleFirstMoves)
    {
        CurrentMove.SetOriginCalculateDestination(PointOfOrigin);
        if (CurrentMove.IsValid() == true) {
            CalculatePath(CurrentMove);
        }
    }
}
```

No need for `else` here, you're throwing an exception. Put guard clauses separate from your code. Like so:

```
if (PossibleFirstMoves.Count == 0)
{
    // Anywhere on the board should have at between 2 and 8 possible moves
    throw new ApplicationException("KnightMovesImplementation::CalculatePaths: No Possible Moves.");
}

foreach (KMMove CurrentMove in PossibleFirstMoves)
{
    CurrentMove.SetOriginCalculateDestination(PointOfOrigin);
    if (CurrentMove.IsValid() == true) {
        CalculatePath(CurrentMove);
    }
}
```

---

```
/*
 * Recursive algorith that performs a depth search.
 * The call to CurrentMove.GetNextLocation() implements the breadth-first portion
 * of the search.
 */
protected void CalculatePath(KMMove CurrentMove)
{
    KMBoardLocation CurrentLocation = CurrentMove.GetNextLocation();
    m_Path.AddMoveToPath(CurrentMove);
    MoveFilter.PushVisited(CurrentLocation);

        if (Destination.IsSameLocation(CurrentLocation) == true)
        {
            Results.IncrementAttemptedPaths();
            Results.AddPath(m_Path);
        }
        else
        {
            if (CurrentMove.IsValid() == true)
            {
                List<KMMove> PossibleMoves = MoveFilter.GetPossibleMoves(CurrentLocation);
                if (PossibleMoves.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (KMMove NextMove in PossibleMoves)
                    {
                        CalculatePath(NextMove);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Results.IncrementAttemptedPaths();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("In KnightMovesImplementation::CalculatePath CurrentLocation Not Valid");
            }
        }
        // Backup to previous location
    MoveFilter.PopVisited();
    m_Path.RemoveLastMove();
}
```

A hiccup with indentation - and more `== true` checks. Also, `else { if(){ } else { }` structures can be converted to `else if() { } else { }` structures:

```
if (Destination.IsSameLocation(CurrentLocation))
{
    Results.IncrementAttemptedPaths();
    Results.AddPath(m_Path);
}
else if (CurrentMove.IsValid())
{
    List<KMMove> PossibleMoves = MoveFilter.GetPossibleMoves(CurrentLocation);
    if (PossibleMoves.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (KMMove NextMove in PossibleMoves)
        {
            CalculatePath(NextMove);
        }
     }
    else
    {
        Results.IncrementAttemptedPaths();
    }
}
else
{
    throw new ApplicationException("In KnightMovesImplementation::CalculatePath CurrentLocation Not Valid");
}
```