# Find all possible ways a rook can move to a diagonally opposite corner without going back to an already visited square

Tags: c#, performance, memory-optimization, chess

This question seems similar to this one: [Find number of unique paths to reach opposite grid corner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/241272/find-number-of-unique-paths-to-reach-opposite-grid-corner) but is entirely not. For moving from upper-left corner to lower-right corner we are not restricted to move only rightwards and downwards otherwise this will be a simple permutation and combination question instead.

I came up with the following very bruteforce method which works perfectly fine for a `boardSize` of `3` (meaning a (3x3) board), `4` and `5` giving `12`, `184` and `8512` successfull paths respectively for reaching `(boardSize, boardSize)` from `(1, 1)`. However the code takes forever for a board size of 6 onwards and I have to make it reach to a standard board size of 8 atleast.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ChessProblem_StackOverFlow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Square currentRookPosition = new Square(1, 1);
            Square destinationPosition = new Square(Square.boardSize, Square.boardSize);    // (3, 3) as of now
            List<Path> paths = new List<Path>();
            List<Path> successfullPaths = new List<Path>();


            // One time initialization of "paths" List based on rook's starting position
            List<Square> possibleMoves = currentRookPosition.GetPossibleMoves();
            foreach (Square nextRookPosition in possibleMoves)
            {
                paths.Add(new Path(currentRookPosition, nextRookPosition));
            }


            while (paths.Any())
            {
                foreach (Path path in paths.ToList())
                {
                    Square lastSquare = path.visitedSquares[^1];
                    List<Square> nextPossibleMoves = lastSquare.GetPossibleMoves();


                    // For each nextPossibleMove check if it is already visited and if so remove it
                    foreach (Square nextPossibleMove in nextPossibleMoves.ToList())
                    {
                        foreach (Square visitedSquare in path.visitedSquares)
                        {
                            if (nextPossibleMove.Equals(visitedSquare))
                            {
                                nextPossibleMoves.RemoveAt(nextPossibleMoves.IndexOf(nextPossibleMove));
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    // Add path to successfullPaths if destination reached
                    if (path.visitedSquares[^1].Equals(destinationPosition))
                    {
                        successfullPaths.Add(path);
                        paths.RemoveAt(paths.IndexOf(path));
                        break;
                    }

                    // Remove path from paths list if out of possible moves
                    if (!nextPossibleMoves.Any())
                    {
                        paths.RemoveAt(paths.IndexOf(path));
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (Square nextPossibleMove in nextPossibleMoves)
                        {
                            // add first move in already running path
                            if (nextPossibleMove.Equals(nextPossibleMoves[0]))
                                path.visitedSquares.Add(new Square(nextPossibleMove.x, nextPossibleMove.y));
                            // create another path for other moves
                            else
                                paths.Add(new Path(path.visitedSquares, nextPossibleMove));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            // test
            foreach (Path path in successfullPaths)
            {
                foreach (Square visitedSquare in path.visitedSquares)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(visitedSquare.x + ", " + visitedSquare.y);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("**********************************************************************");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Number of successfull paths: " + successfullPaths.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `Square` struct with only `GetPossibleMoves()` method which gives all possible moves irrespective of whether it is already visited or not, I am taking care of that in my `Main()` method.

```
struct Square
{
    public int x, y;
    public static int boardSize = 3;
    public Square(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public List<Square> GetPossibleMoves()
    {
        List<Square> possibleMoves = new List<Square>();
        if (x > 1)
            possibleMoves.Add(new Square(x - 1, y));
        if (x < boardSize)
            possibleMoves.Add(new Square(x + 1, y));
        if (y > 1)
            possibleMoves.Add(new Square(x, y - 1));
        if (y < boardSize)
            possibleMoves.Add(new Square(x, y + 1));
        return possibleMoves;
    }
}
```

And here is my `Path` class for keeping track of `visitedSquares` in any instance of this class.

```
class Path
{
    Square from, to;
    public List<Square> visitedSquares = new List<Square>();
    
    public Path(Square from, Square to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        visitedSquares.Add(new Square(from.x, from.y));
        visitedSquares.Add(new Square(to.x, to.y));
    }
    // another constructor
    public Path(List<Square> listToBeExtendedFrom, Square replaceLastSquareWith)
    {
        foreach(Square square in listToBeExtendedFrom)
        {
            visitedSquares.Add(new Square(square.x, square.y));
        }
        visitedSquares.Remove(visitedSquares[visitedSquares.Count - 1]);
        visitedSquares.Add(new Square(replaceLastSquareWith.x, replaceLastSquareWith.y));
    }
}
```

For a `boardSize` of `6`, I let this program run for half an hour which used upto 6 GB of memory but didn't gave any output. How can I make this more efficient?

As [@G. Sliepen](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/129343/g-sliepen) and [@pacmaninbw](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/79357/pacmaninbw) mentioned in this [follow up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/269813/find-all-possible-ways-a-rook-can-move-c-version) question about **Rook or king moves**, the question meant to say as if we were tracing the rook's path, the rook isn't allowed to revisit an already visited square **neither it is allowed to intersect it's own path**. My bad I didn't already mentioned this but I pre assumed this as otherwise the question would have become really clumsy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend that you change `struct Square` to `record Square`. This makes all the comparative stuff much easier.

Then you can change your `Program` class to the following which uses recursion to find the paths. I have also added a timer to show progress.

```
class Program
{
    static void GetPaths(List<Square> path, Square currentRookPosition, Square destinationPosition, int level)
    {
        path.Add(currentRookPosition);
        if (currentRookPosition == destinationPosition)
        {
            pathsFound++;
            return;
        }

        List<Square> possibleMoves = currentRookPosition.GetPossibleMoves();
        foreach (Square nextRookPosition in possibleMoves)
        {
            if (path.Contains(nextRookPosition) == false)
            {
                GetPaths(path.ToList(), nextRookPosition, destinationPosition, level + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        sw.Start();
        using (var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000))
        {
            timer.Elapsed += ShowProgress;
            timer.Start();

            var currentRookPosition = new Square(1, 1);
            var destinationPosition = new Square(Square.boardSize, Square.boardSize);    // (3, 3) as of now
            var path = new List<Square>();
            GetPaths(path, currentRookPosition, destinationPosition, 0);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Paths found = " + pathsFound);
    }

    private static void ShowProgress(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("paths found = {0}, second = {1}", pathsFound, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000));
    }

    private static int pathsFound = 0;
    private static System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
}
```

This finds 1 262 816 paths for a 6x6 grid in about 20 seconds.

---

Here is a revised implementation that calculates a 6x6 grid in under a second using bitsets and pre-calculated moves:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ChessProblem_StackOverFlow
{
    class Board
    {
        public Board(int cols, int rows)
        {
            this.cols = cols;
            this.rows = rows;
            this.squares = new int[cols * rows][];
            for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
                {
                    squares[x + y * cols] = calcMoves(x, y);
                }
            }
        }

        int[] calcMoves(int x, int y)
        {
            var moves = new List<int>();
            if (x > 0)
                moves.Add(calcIndex(x - 1, y));
            if (x < cols - 1)
                moves.Add(calcIndex(x + 1, y));
            if (y > 0)
                moves.Add(calcIndex(x, y - 1));
            if (y < rows - 1)
                moves.Add(calcIndex(x, y + 1));
            return moves.ToArray();
        }

        public int calcIndex(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y * cols;
        }

        public UInt64 calcBit(int index)
        {
            UInt64 one = 1;
            return one << index;
        }

        public int rows;
        public int cols;
        public int[][] squares;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void GetPaths(UInt64 path, int currentRookPosition, int destinationPosition, int level)
        {
            path |= board.calcBit(currentRookPosition);
            if (currentRookPosition == destinationPosition)
            {
                pathsFound++;
                return;
            }

            foreach (int nextRookPosition in board.squares[currentRookPosition])
            {
                if ((UInt64)(path & board.calcBit(nextRookPosition)) == (UInt64)0)
                {
                    GetPaths(path, nextRookPosition, destinationPosition, level + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            sw.Start();
            using (var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000))
            {
                timer.Elapsed += ShowProgress;
                timer.Start();

                int size = 6;
                board = new Board(size, size);
                var currentRookPosition = board.calcIndex(0, 0);
                var destinationPosition = board.calcIndex(board.cols - 1, board.rows - 1);
                
                UInt64 path = 0;
                GetPaths(path, currentRookPosition, destinationPosition, 0);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Paths found = " + pathsFound);
        }

        private static void ShowProgress(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("paths found = {0}, second = {1}", pathsFound, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000));
        }
        private static int pathsFound = 0;
        private static System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        private static Board board;
    }
}
```

It took about 2 minutes to calculate 575 780 564 paths for a 7x7 grid. I will leave the 8x8 up to you...

PS. For my own amusement, I created a [C++ version](https://bit.ly/3CSwWBF) that is about 2 times faster than the C# one. Still waiting for the results for 8x8 :-)

Comment: Wow, that's a HUUUUGE upgrade, but still far from achieving 8*8. Seems like the number will be really really monstrous. Will try implementing your suggestions.

Comment: I changed `struct` to `record` and let the recursion version run overnight for 7x7 grid. The last line was `Paths found = 575780564, second = 23135`. 6 hours compared to 2 minutes!!! Orz I am just a beginner and this is getting overwhelmingly good.

Comment: @Prince, cool! I have posted a [follow up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/269813/find-all-possible-ways-a-rook-can-move-c-version) question that you may want to keep an eye on =)

Comment: I have found that these types of programs are generally faster in C++. I answered a C# question about the Knights Tour problem then wrote a [C++ version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132876/knights-tour-improved-refactored-recursive-breadth-first-search-for) to test my algorithm. Then I wrote a [C# version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133674/recursive-breadth-first-search-knights-tour) that was faster than the original question.

Comment: @pacmaninbw, I agree and I think that if there is any way to speed this up fundamentally, the same logic should be applicable to the C# version. I posted the C++ version to attract a different audience and see what they can come up with =)

Comment: Yes, and some of the things pointed out in the answer will help this C# question as well. Especially `prune early`.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Added clarification about **rook or king move** in the question.

Comment: @upkajdt `int[] m = calcMoves(x, y);` is not used, and it adds more time and memory for nothing. remove it to improve the performance. ;)

Comment: @iSR5, well spotted =)